# Creating an IDL file from a DLL

Tags: windows, multithreading, vb6, idl, midl

I'm working on a VB6 graphical interface that make use of a DLL generated from a C code that makes use of `__declspec(thread)` variables. The problem is that because of a [known limitation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118816), it is not possible to dynamically link this dll in the VB6 project.

So, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195605/vb-linking-a-dll-in-implicit-way) discussion, a possible solution is to create an IDL file from the DLL, compile it with a MIDL compiler, and then reference the resulting .tlb file in the VB6 project.

I'm able to generate the .tlb file until I have to specify functions that contain struct variables

```
[
  uuid(YOURTYPE-LIBG-UIDH-ERE0-000000000000),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring ("My Type Library 1.0")
]
library MyTypeLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [dllname("OLEAUT32")]
    module OleAut32
    {
        [entry("myFunct")]
        int myFunct([in] myStruct data);
    };
};
```

At the row:  `int myFunct([in] myStruct data);` the compiler says:

`syntax error: expecting a type specification near "myStruct"`

Is there a way to make it works? Like some kind of struct declaration in the IDL file?

Thank you,

G.B.

SOLVED [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195605/vb-linking-a-dll-in-implicit-way) by wqw. Thanks

Comment: What does the C function signature of the DLL look like?  What is "the bug" that prevents dynamic linking in the first place?

Comment: @selbie Hi, I didn't understand the first question, sorry. Regarding the limitation you can find the explanation at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118816

Comment: @David Thank you, I already fixed the question.

Comment: Closed as localized as you have solved the problem, eliminating any answers being posted.