# How to do "Public Declare Ansi Function" in Visual Basic 6.0?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, urlmon

I'm trying to convert this VB.NET / C# declaration into a Visual Basic 6.0 one, having trouble (included is the C# version, converting to VB.NET not a problem):

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(
    int dwOption,
    string pBuffer,
    int dwBufferLength,
    int dwReserved);
```

As you can see, in Visual Basic/C# we have that `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` part, which I don't know how to do in Visual Basic 6.0 - I tried adding the A at the end of the Alias Name... `Alias "UrlMkSetSessionOptionA"` ... but that didn't work (says `can't find DLL entrypoint in urlmon.dll`). Without this, the string sent to pBuffer is coming out as gibberish (weird characters I can't recognize).

Here is what I've gotten so far...

```vb
Public Declare Sub UrlMkSetSessionOption Lib "urlmon.dll" (ByVal _
    dwOption As Long, _
    pBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal dwBufferLength As Long, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long)
```

Comment: VB6 doesn't have this option, it always assumes ANSI strings.  So what you got is already good, other than Function over Sub.  How you can see gibberish is hard to guess.  I wouldn't expect this API function to still have any effect these days.

Comment: @Hans Passant thank you for your comments. Could you elaborate on what you mean re: "I wouldn't expect this API function to still have any effect these days"? Is there an alternative or updated function to use instead of UrlMkSetSessionOption or? If so, would love to hear about it. I'm trying to change the User-Agent of WebBrowser control hosted in my session, but WebBrowser control buiilt-in methods dont do this for all requests. Is InternetSetOption capable of doing this? Once again thank you for your valued contribution.

Comment: Ask the real question, not this one.  Nobody can guess what "dont do this for all requests" might mean.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm not asking the "real" question because I don't want to go there, i'm trying to figure out this option only as i've exhausted all the other options to dead ends, over several days recently and even more years ago. I just wanted to know what you meant by this function not being relevant any longer... if you could elaborate on that it could be useful for me.

Comment: Wininet dates from the previous century.  No modern software uses it anymore, including IE.

Comment: @Hans passant msinet.ocx is wrapper around wininet if I recall correctly, ppl stuck with vb6 still end up having to use it. It's interesting because I just used it and it's working even in ie9 - so I'm guessing ie9 is still using urlmon perhaps with a fancy wrapper around it, but underlying API still seems to be the same as there is no other API way of doing what I mentioned in the question (that being changing user agent of a hosted web browser control for apps process using API without changing it system-wide). Oh the efforts we go to, to respect users system configurations and settings :)

Comment: I'd love to see something authoritative stating that IE no longer uses WinInet, because there seems to be plenty stating that it does.

Comment: VB6 does not "always assume ANSI strings."  There is no problem calling standard DLLs passing either ANSI or Unicode by as you choose.  Of course it helps if you actually *know* VB6 and how to declare the entrypoints and perform the calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured out that the declaration is correct, and there was a particular way that it needed to be called - basically you need to pass the string as ByVal - it just randomly worked while I was trying a combination of different things. Thank you for everyone for their contribution. Here is the call if declared as a sub.

```
UrlMkSetSessionOption URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, ByVal strUA, Len(strUA), 0
```

I hope this is useful to someone - when you call the second argument without the "ByVal strUA" and just pass "strUA" the internal function must assume ByRef, which means it is trying to use the variable we passed it (an ANSI Visual Basic 6.0 STRING), and of course, when it does this, it ends up as gibberish as the **string** type the C function uses is not an ANSI Visual Basic string type.

So, when passing it as ByVal it just passes it by value (not by reference) and can then use its own variable/datatype combination which is compatible with the string type it uses. I hope that helps someone.

Comment: If you pass ByRef it will pass VB6's own internal Unicode BStr. ByVal invokes automatic conversion into ANSI and passed a pointer to that string.

Comment: Actually, passing to a ByRef As String argument creates an ANSI-copy CHAR array and passes the address of (i.e. by reference) a pointer to that, on return the ANSI CHAR data is copied back with conversion to Unicode.  ByVal As String does the same copy to/from ANSI but passes the pointer (by value) of the 1st char of the ANSI BSTR.

Comment: If you want to pass the actual Unicode string by value declare the argument ByVal As Long and pass StrPtr(string).  To pass by reference declare ByVal As Long and pass VarPtr(string), but this is very rarely used in Win32 APIs.

Answer (score 3):

You declare the VB6 function as `Sub`, making the compiler/interpreter look for a `void` function (also known as procedure), while the actual function has an `int` return type.

It should work if you change your include statement to this:

```vb
Public Declare Function UrlMkSetSessionOption Lib "urlmon.dll" (ByVal _
    dwOption As Long, _
    pBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal dwBufferLength As Long, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Long
```

It may be that you'll also have to replace all occurences of `Long` with `Integer`, but due to my lack of experience with VB6 I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried changing to a function with integer & long return types, i even tried changing variables to integers +all combos of the above. Results are still the same. interestingly, im passing a string which i havent changed between tests about 20 characters long, and what comes out is always a changing/different string of about 3-7 chars long, mostly consisting of non-keyword characters. I see the result by visiting whatsmyuseragent.com through the webbrowser control in my form, so function is working, but the string turns into gibberish somewhere along the way...?

Comment: once again thank you for your contribution [upvoted], however i have solved it by trying a few random things. Feel free to refer to the answer i've provided if you are curious as to what it was.

Answer (score 0):

```
Const URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = &H10000001
Const URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH = &H10000002
```

Private Declare Function UrlMkSetSessionOption Lib "urlmon" (ByVal dwOption As Long, ByVal pBuffer As String, ByVal dwBufferLength As Long, ByVal dwReserved As Long) As Integer

Public Function ChangeUserAgent

```
(Optional ByVal MyUserAgent As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36")

 Call UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH, vbNullString, 0, 0)

 Call UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, MyUserAgent, LenB(MyUserAgent), 0)
```

End Function