# VB6 declaration for C++ function gives "Bad DLL calling convention"

Tags: c++, vb6, calling-convention

What is the correct VB6 declaration for this C++ function?

```cpp
LPCWSTR* MW_ListReaders(_ULONG Context, int* NumberOfReaders);
```

The following gave me "Bad DLL calling convention":

```vb
Private Declare Function ListReaders Lib "MyDLL.dll" (ByVal Context As Long, _
                                                    ByRef NumberOfReaders As Integer) As Long
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no calling convention specified in that C++ declaration.  Most C/C++ compilers default to `__cdecl`.  If the function does actually use `__cdecl` then you will not be able to call it in VB6:

[How To Call C Functions That Use the _cdecl Calling Convention](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153586)

> It is not possible to directly call a C function in a DLL if that function uses the _cdecl calling convention. This is because Visual Basic uses the _stdcall calling convention for calling functions. This is a problem because if _cdecl is used, the calling function is responsible for cleaning up the stack. However, if _stdcall is used, the called function is responsible for cleaning up the stack.
>
> NOTE: An .EXE file created in Visual Basic will allow you to call a DLL function that has been declared with the _cdecl calling convention without an error. It is only when you try to call such a function when running a program from the Visual Basic IDE, that Visual Basic generates the following error:
>
> Run-time Error '49':
>   Bad DLL Calling Convention
>
> The fact that the EXE version allows you to call such functions has been confirmed to be a bug by Microsoft. You should not rely on this behavior as this might change in future versions of Visual Basic.

Comment: The important word from the quoted documentation is *directly*. You can call a `cdecl` function from VB6 if it's [described in a type library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5196051/11683).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Remy's answer, you have also got the Vb declaration slightly wrong:

```
Private Declare Function ListReaders Lib "MyDLL.dll" (ByVal Context As Long, ByRef NumberOfReaders As Long) As Long
```

"Integer" is a 2 byte integer in vb.

Comment: So what about the _ULONG then? Is it 64 bit?

Comment: No - It is defined in windows.h as being a 32-bit unsigned integer. VB doesn't support unsigned integers, so you have to fake it with a signed 32-bit integer, i.e. "As Long"