# How to add attribute "CallingConvention" to Declare statement when calling dll?

Tags: vb.net, dllimport, declare

In VB.NET, to import a method from DLL file can be written in:

1. `DllImport` statement - new method introduced for .net
2. `Declare` statement - old method since VB6

For the first one, the code looks like:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
<DllImport("library_name.dll", EntryPoint:="entry_point", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> Public Function method_name(...) AS ...
End Function
```

And the above code works fine, I just wonder how to convert the code into the older way using Declare keyword as following:

```
Declare Function method_name Lib "library_name.dll" Alias "entry_point" (...) As ...
```

To make the question more specific, where can I add the `CallingConvention` attribute into the `Declare` statement?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use the older method, when the newer one works?

Comment: It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293334/vb6-declaration-for-c-function-gives-bad-dll-calling-convention) the older syntax/VB6 is limited to `__stdcall`.

Answer (score 1):

The legavy `Declare` syntax is limited to `stdcall`. Use p/invoke.